# Are identifications of Anime Characters allowed on S&F?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, questions, anime

When I went to visit S&F I noticed a particular question which was asking for a anime character identification request. You can view the question [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51655/what-anime-has-a-character-becoming-aware-of-cows-suffering-when-eating-a-burger). Is this allowed? Why do we have a [anime] tag, and should questions in general like these be migrated to Anime StackExchange?

Also did you allow this question because the anime is related to Fantasy or Scifi? Should anything related to Anime be migrated, rather than stand on this site?

I am asking for some help on the matter. Do you agree with this or disagree and what's your advice on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Also did you allow this question because the anime is related to Fantasy or Scifi?

Yes these questions are definitely within the scope of the site.

No we should not migrate all anime content to anime.stackexchange. If that we're the case it could be argued that it is equally fair to migrate all sci-fi and  fantasy content of other sites to this one.

In the event that a question referencing a SFF anime is more concerned with anime aspects such as production etc. (E.g. Why does season 2 of Guren Lagan start so differently compared to season 1?) Then I feel there is a strong argument for migrating it. Likewise a reverse case may exist.

Comment: Okay. Good point with that. It could cause a stir. We don't really want that happening.

Comment: I think it's a value judgement. If it's a non-scifi/fantasy anime then the call is obviously much easier to make.

Comment: It's also worth remembering that content shouldn't be migrated to *beta* sites.  Even if there's a strong case for migration, beta sites are supposed to stand or fall on their own, not have content migrated to them.

Answer (score 5):

If it's science fiction or fantasy, then it's on-topic here. Otherwise, it's off-topic. And if it's on-topic here, then it shouldn't be migrated or closed. The fact that a question may be on-topic somewhere else is irrelevant. (Indeed, another site that largely overlaps with this one is [Movies and TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/).)

On the Anime & Manga site, identification questions are usually off-topic. [Here](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4190)'s what **is *on-topic***:

> 1. [Characters from a known series](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4187)
> 2. Episodes from a known series (this includes some anime/manga-style series of non-Japanese origin)
> 3. [Music from a known series](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4054) - ask with [[music] and [series-name] tags](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=music) (e.g. [[music]](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music) [[naruto]](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naruto))
>
>    - For Vocaloid songs: [yes, but with some exceptions](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4175).
> 4. Cosplay/merchandise/*itasha*: [yes, but with some exceptions](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4142)

Also note that the current policy on Movies & TV is that all identification questions are [off-topic](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4087/70064).